# Handling Request at serverside with C# web api

Tags: c#, laravel

I want to handle the requests made from the swift app at C#. Before using C# I was using php on laravel framework. Laravel has type of Request

to demonstrate a short example my methods were like

```
function MyFindById(Request &request){    
   $name = $request->input('name');
}
```

is there any C# equivalent of this? where I could fetch the keyvalue pair I sent with swift ? and also how do I get the request data? like when it is sent, or device info,header and so on..

I apologize for my poor english by the way

Comment: Well yes and no. You could read it from Request object in the controller but c# is intended to be strongly typed so making a Poco object is recommended. For Json requests you can have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization). By default form and xml requests are supported.

Comment: Strictly speaking C# MVC has the [`Request`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.request(v=vs.118).aspx) property in the controller which exposes (among other things) the [query string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a new C# WebAPI project using the Visual Studio template that is included with the web development installation or the .net CLI.

Once you have your project created there will be multiple ways you can access the request data.

Here are a couple ways to fetch the key value pair.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post()
        {
            var name = HttpContext.Request.Form["name"].ToString();            
        }

        [HttpPost("post-my-request")]
        public void Post([FromBody]MyRequest myRequest)
        {
            var name = myRequest.name;
        }
    }

    public class MyRequest
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The first will access the form encoded field "name" at /api/values.

The second approach leverages the WebAPI model binder to serialize the request into an object.  I prefer this approach.  This will access the data at /api/values/post-my-request

Comment: what is the version of .Net Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET and Web Tools installed.